# Google Maps Android API v2 application crash

Tags: android, dictionary, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to get the sample code of Android 'Google Maps Android API v2' working. I get the project built without errors. However, when I try to run the app on Everpad , the app crashes immediately.

The logcat output:

```
08-30 17:12:42.620: E/dalvikvm(4352): Could not find class 'com.dvp.android.gallery.GPS', referenced from method com.dvp.android.gallery.Acceuil$5.onClick
08-30 17:12:47.670: E/InputDispatcher(3263): Motion event has invalid action code 0xa
08-30 17:12:47.760: E/InputDispatcher(3263): Motion event has invalid action code 0x9
08-30 17:12:47.760: E/InputDispatcher(3263): Motion event has invalid action code 0x7
08-30 17:12:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 17:12:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4352): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dvp.android.gallery.GPS
08-30 17:12:47.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4352):     at com.dvp.android.gallery.Acceuil$5.onClick(Acceuil.java:57)
```

The Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.dvp.android.gallery"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <permission
            android:name="com.dvp.android.gallery.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_bardo" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Acceuil"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Objets" android:label="Objets">  </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GPS"
                  android:label="GPS">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Detail" android:label="Detail"></activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".Galeries"
                android:label="Galeries"
                />
        <activity
                android:name=".Evennements"
                android:label="Evennements"/>
        <activity
                android:name=".Infos"
                android:label="Infos"/>
    </application>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA0HMTTGLqlYaq6jOuS0imbjt7GmUHyK0c"/>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />


    <uses-permission android:name="com.dvp.android.gallery.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

The Java Code

```
package com.dvp.android.gallery;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


public class GPS extends FragmentActivity{

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gps);
       SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
       fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();

    }


}
```

And Finally the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
/>
```

I googled and found no information about this exception. I'm really confused about this problem and don't know how to fix it. Does anyone have idea how to fix it? **Thanks.**

Comment: The google map sample is a bear to get going.  Keep trying you'll get it.

Comment: are you renamed your class or package.

Comment: No I didn't rename any thing

Comment: have you add google-play-services library?

Comment: Yes I have added google-play-services library but my emulator could not show the google Map

Answer (score 0):

There is some kind of mismatch between the package you specified in your Manifest file and the package you have provided for the Activities in it.

try to change:

```
 <activity
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationgooglemapv2demo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

to:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and don't write some package with cased latters and some not, change your permissions package to be as it's written in the package section:

```
 <permission
      android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.LocationGoogleMapV2Demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.LocationGoogleMapV2Demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Comment: I changed evry thnig but still dosen't Work

Comment: well I don't see anything wrong with. Try to recreate the project. Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

you can implement following:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icn_button2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.gc.materialdesigndemo.ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="br.com.informapa.MESSAGE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```